# Hide some input messages to MS teams bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am building a bot that takes some sensitive inputs. As I would like to add this bot to an MS team/group, how do I hide/mask user's input to the bot from other users. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it's not possible to send masking data to bot from compose message area. Instead you can use adaptive card to send masking data to bot.

```
{
      "type": "Input.Text",
      "id": "secretThing",
      "style": "password"
}
```

[image]

Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience, some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, we also recommend you give your new idea in Teams UserVoice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) if this needs to be consider as a future request.

Comment: great, thanks for the suggestion.
Have given my idea in the UserVoice.
https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/43493343-sending-sensitive-message-to-a-specific-user-bot-i